# Android - ImageView - Multiple Screen Support - Set height/width as dp or match_parent/wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I am currently trying to adjust my Android App so it will look and feel similar on multiple screens/devices.

I know by now that a major part in this is to provide multiple image sizes for every image file according to the x1, x1.5, x2, x3, x4 ratios for mdpi, hdpi, xhpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi respectively, and I have finished doing so today.

After doing this, I have defined `Density independent Pixel` dimensions in the @dimen.xml values resource that correspond with the actual image sizes in pixels of the MDPI resources. Subsequently, i have set the imageviews in question's `layout_width` and `layout_height` to this dimension.

I am currently at a loss, however, as to why my application still looks significantly different on an MDPI emulator than it does on an HDPI emulator. To highlight what I mean, I'll provide the following screenshot showing the HDPI and MPDI emulator next to one another (left is HDPI (`4" WVGA Nexus S`) and right is MDPI (`5.4" FWVGA`)). I want both of them to look like the MPDI version, but what I've done so far apparently isn't working.

[image]
[image]

I have three theories of my own as to why this is not working the way I intend it to:

**1.** I am not supposed to set ImageView `layout_width` and `layout_height` to a dp value, but rather `match_parent` or `wrap_content` (?) (and change the structure of my .xml layouts in the process).

**2.** I am not only supposed to define multiple drawable resources, but also multiple layout resources for different screen sizes (?).

**3.** I have misunderstood the entire idea behind how this is supposed to work (?).

I will also give you an example of one of the list items that can be seen in the first screenshot (`@drawable/phone_speed_icon` is a `64 x64` pixel resource in MPDI and a `96x96` resource in HDPI, and `@dimen/icon_attribute_size` is `64dp`):

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSpeed_PreSession"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_attribute_size"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:weightSum="100">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="70"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_attribute_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_attribute_size"
                        android:src="@drawable/phone_speed_icon" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="30"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text="Speed"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                    android:textColor="#878787"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:gravity="center">

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/swSpeed_PreSession"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

In the end, I have four questions that I'd like answered:

**1.** How do I make the list items in screenshot 1 look the same on MDPI devices as HDPI devices? Does this have anything to do with one of the three theories I mentioned earlier?

**2.** Why is the header text ("What do you want to measure?") wrapped on one device, but not on the other? They use the `sp` unit (via `android:style/TextApperance.TextApperance.Large`)?

**3.** Shouldn't everything be more spaced out on an HDPI device (if anything) rather than less spaced out? The HDPI emulator looks as if it "has got way less pixels available", if you can understand what I'm saying even a little.

**4.** How do I make the Fragments on the second screenshot look the same? Or should i not even want this, because the HDPI is (for some reason) physically smaller, which is why the layout is less spread out?

Anyway, I have been at this all day and the more I read the more thouroughly confused I get, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to create multiple `dimens.xml` files depending on a variety of factors. Here you'll see what my current project looks like with the various `dimens.xml` files in Android Studio based on screen width.

[image: Res values]

However, you can have different requirements for each `dimens` file you want. For example, you can create `dimens` files for each density:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So basically it means i have not only got to create seperate drawable files, but also seperate layout files AND seperate dimens files? This all seems really inefficient. Also - do you intend to say i should create a smaller `dp` entry in the HDPI dimens.xml file?

Comment: You don't have to create separate layout files. But if you truly want your app to look THE SAME on all dimensions, then yes, you'll have to create different dimens files.
As for your other question, take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) if you haven't already. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I have indeed read (most of) the link you provided, but i do not seem to get the result they show under the `Density Independence` header. They tell me to simply define the dimensions as `dp` instead of `px`, and the system will then draw the drawable exactly as big on any density screen. I have done what they told me, but one is still bigger than the other. Have you got any idea as to why this is the case then? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How much bigger is one versus the other? There is no guarantee that the values you define will be EXACTLY the same on every screen. Keep in mind that Android supports almost 8,000 different devices with ranging densities. It's nearly impossible to get things to look identical on EVERY screen.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/appendix-c-everything-about-sizes-and-dimensions-in-android/) as well

Comment: Hmm fair enough. I will give the different dimens.xml resources a try in the morning and see if that gets me what i want. Thanks a lot for the help! I have one more question though, just for curiosity: If two devices have the same DPI but different screen sizes, how will those compare? Will the layout be equally spaced, but just stretched to a bigger/smaller screen? Edit: that last link shows promising, i'll give it a read, thank you!

Comment: Depending on the way you've configured your layouts, chances are the the views will have more spacing in between or look thinner/stretched out  (ex phone vs tablet)